Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error). javas +html , recaptchaVerifier error with fairebase auth docs
this is my first question here =).
I'm working on a web page with firebase and VScode editor .(self learning)
every thing was ok until I paste auth code from firebase (from old namespaced API) to VScode then this error appeared on web bage console :
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
code index.html on the editor :
<body>
   
    <h1>login to website</h1>
    <input id="phone" placeholder="phone"/>
    <input id="otp" placeholder="otp"/>
    <div id="recaptcha-container"> </div>
    <button onclick="login()">sign-in</button>


  <script src="/js/main.js"></script> 
</body>

the code in main.js with error line in recaptchaVerification:
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
  const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref();

  function login() {
    const phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    const recaptchaVerifier =new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');

       alert("hi");
   })

  }

I really appreciate your help ..
solving the problem with explain it =)

Where exactly did you copy that code from?  Are you expecting to use the old namespaced API or the new modular API?  Please edit the question to be clear.
